# SpriteKit Game - SKScene Freezes during In-App Purchase in iOS 8.3

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, skscene, ios8.3

I have developed my first SpriteKit game and implemented in-app purchase in SKScence (not UIViewController). In my SKScene, there are locked items and all have zPosition<=+10. When user touches on any locked item, a transparent background (SKSpriteNode named "bgTransparent") appears on the top of all those items with zPosition=+20 and then another SKSpriteNode named "connectingMSG" (an image with message "connecting to Apple Store") appears on the top of transparent background with zPosition=+30. Once purchase is made, then I am removing  locks, bgTransparent and connectingMSG using "removeFromParent"

```html
bgTransparent =[SKSpriteNode
                        spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bg_New_Moon_1_2320.png"];
        
        [bgTransparent setScale:.25];
        bgTransparent.size = self.frame.size; 
        bgTransparent.position= CGPointMake(0,0);
        bgTransparent.zPosition= +20;
        bgTransparent.alpha=0.55; 
        bgTransparent.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        bgTransparent.name=@"bgTransparent";
        [self addChild:bgTransparent];
        
        connectingMSG =[SKSpriteNode
                        spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"connectingTo_1.png"];
        
        [connectingMSG setScale:.36];
        connectingMSG.position= CGPointMake(self.size.width/2-60, 80);
        connectingMSG.zPosition= +30; // top of bgTransparent
        connectingMSG.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        connectingMSG.name=@"connectingMSG";
        [self addChild:connectingMSG];
```

```html
[connectingMSG removeFromParent];
[bgTransparent removeFromParent];
```

In-app purchase is working fine in iOS 8.2. I tested it on iPad with iOS 8.2 and all simulators (iOS8.2). I also developed this game in Xcode 6.2 with base SDK iOS 8.2. Submitted it to APPLE and game got REJECTED because they tested it on iOS 8.3 and they found a bug (no crash). In iOS 8.3, user can buy and complete In App Purchase, Purchase confirmation appears, Tap on OK and modal alert disappears but  no further action occurs and In App Purchase remains locked.

I upgraded my iPad to iOS 8.3 and what happening is that scene is freezing as soon as in app purchase screen appears. For Example: connectingMSG,bgtransparent are not being removed even if I click cancel on following screen and don't sign-in while they disappear in iOS 8.2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3O3K.png

same happens when I sign-in and make purchase. It freezes and nothing happens after touching again and again.

In console, it shows all NSLog messages that I am using after removing connectingMSG, bgTransparent and locks. So I know that code is running till end and removefromParent code i. It just doesn't remove SpriteNodes and refresh screen.

It is still working fine on iOS 8.2 but not on iOS 8.3.  How do I fix it? Is it freezing because I am purchasing directly from SKScence (not UIViewController).

Please reply.

Comment: Obviously you did something somewhere in your code. I suggest you liberally sprinkle your relevant code with NSLog statements and see where exactly the issue is. Also, your posted code does not appear to have any relevance to your app freezing on the purchase / sign-in screen.